# When I used the backup tool cbbackup of couchbase,i meet a exception in thread w2

Tags: multithreading, exception, backup, couchbase

when i use the couchbase cbbackup to backup my data,i meet a question like this .

```
E:\couchbase\bin>cbbackup -m diff http://localhost:8091 E:\couchbase_backup - 
u Administrator -p password

 [                    ] 0.0% (0/estimated 7303 msgs)
 [enter image description here][1]bucket: beer-sample, msgs transferred...
   :                total |       last |    per sec
  byte  :                    0 |          0 |        0.0
  .
 bucket: bucket-beer-sample, msgs transferred...
   :                total |       last |    per sec
 byte  :                    0 |          0 |        0.0
 [                    ] 0.0% (0/estimated 586 msgs)
bucket: bucket-gamesim-sample, msgs transferred...
   :                total |       last |    per sec
byte  :                    0 |          0 |        0.0
[                    ] 0.0% (0/estimated 31369 msgs)
bucket: bucket-travel-sample, msgs transferred...
   :                total |       last |    per sec
byte  :                    0 |          0 |        0.0
[####################] 100.0% (586/estimated 586 msgs)
bucket: gamesim-sample, msgs transferred...
   :                total |       last |    per sec
byte  :                94693 |      94693 |    20342.2
Exception in thread w1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "threading.pyc", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
File "threading.pyc", line 504, in run
File "pump.pyc", line 302, in run_worker
File "pump.pyc", line 360, in run
File "pump_dcp.pyc", line 180, in provide_batch
File "pump_dcp.pyc", line 508, in get_dcp_conn
File "pump_dcp.pyc", line 629, in setup_dcp_streams
File "pump_dcp.pyc", line 649, in request_dcp_stream
File "cb_bin_client.pyc", line 65, in _sendMsg
error: [Errno 10053]
```

I don't know how to resloving it. I stuck it in two days ,please help me. thanks.
By the way.It doesn't happen two days ago. The exception sometimes is "Exception in thread w2".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzXTl.png

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I saw it too late.My version of couchbase is 4.6.Is my version too old?I will try the new version.Thank you.

Comment: Hello，sir.I change the version of my couchbase .My question is sovled.I want to know if the data of couchbase is restored to a specific point in time? For example, it was restored to 1 o'clock yesterday afternoon. I also want to know the difference incremental backup of couchbase is specifically carried out at what time? Thank you.